# Magento 2 Export Button CSV and XML Catalog Product Problem

Tags: magento2, catalog, csv, export, product-grid

I added **Export Button** to the **grid catalog** but still the following problem appears :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.
#0 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection/Interceptor.php(947): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventor...', 'qty', 'product_id=enti...', '{{table}}.stock...', 'left')
#1 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddQuantityFieldToCollection.php(27): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventor...', 'qty', 'product_id=enti...', '{{table}}.stock...', 'left')
#2 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php(88): Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddQuantityFieldToCollection->addField(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor), 'qty', NULL)
#3 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(116): Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider->addField('qty')
#4 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(69): Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->addFieldToSelect()
#5 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(168): Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare()
#6 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php(166): Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column))
```

......

Comment: did u fix it? I've a similar issue

Comment: I have the same issue, please give solution for this.

Comment: Could you fix it?

Comment: have you got the solution?